# need different image with each instance of the same class

Tags: jquery, css

I tried searching for this or something close, but I couldn't find something to work with.  I'm not a programmer and I got this far by reverse engineering existing code. This seems like this would be a common question. I am building a photo-mantage, a mosaic of small images. when the user mouses over, I want a smaller image to pop up. I want to use a class because there will be hundreds of images. Divs and ids won't work because it would get too large. So, here is my markup, and the js. Since I'm a new user here, it will only let me post one hyperlink and no images. But there will be multiple `<li>`'s with an image class "bigFoo". How can I get it to act on EACH individual "bigFoo" class? Any advice would be great.

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function show_img(){
      $("document").ready(function() {
      $(".bigFoo") .css("visibility", "visible");
     });
     }

     function hide_img(){
     $("document").ready(function() {
      $(".bigFoo") .css("visibility", "hidden");
     });
     }
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseOver="show_img()" onMouseOut="hide_img()">
<image src="#littleA" /></a><image class="bigFoo" src="#bigA" /></li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use **jQuery**. Make sure you uploaded it to your server and you're linking to it in your HTML code, like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: so as not to confuse, i added the jQuery library in my example. i thought i tagged this as jQuery, but anyway, that's not the issue. the jQuery library is working, the code is "sorta" working. when i mouse over either image, it displays "both" images, instead of the image that is specific to each instance of the image class "bigFoo" within the <li>. i want one CSS class, but to display only the image particular to that list item.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the basic idea of what you are looking for?

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/UqpEQ/)

Comment: sort of. when you mouse over each item, i want to larger image that pertains to that smaller image to appear. does this make sense. take your exmaple, and use a cloud image in one box, and a circle in the other. then when you mouse over, pop up either a larger image of the cloud, or a larger image of the circle, and use only one class. i know i can do this using id's, but if i have 500 pictures, then i have 500 ids.

Comment: Nalum, i think your example might work, i will have to play with it. cools site btw.

Comment: Nalum,thanks up front for your efforts. this second idea is close. using your solution, here is what i'm trying to do. take your first cloud image, make a small version, then a larger one. (for now i guess you can scale but i prefer to use two different sizes.) when you mouse over the cloud, the larger version of the cloud appears. Then in the second list item, use a completely different image, lets say a ball, and make two versions, a small and a large. then when you mouse over the this ball (contained in the second li), the larger version of the ball will appear.

Comment: where I have the css to change the height and width you can change the src so that it points to another file. So say you have two files for the ball image ball_small.jpg & ball_big.jpg you could use the same javascript but do the following instead of `.css()` http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/UqpEQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($){ //best way to do document.ready

$('.hoverLink').mouseenter(function(e){
 $(this).find('.littleFoo').hide();
 $(this).find('.bigFoo').show();
});

$('.hoverLink').mouseleave(function(e){
  $(this).find('.littleFoo').show();
  $(this).find('.bigFoo').hide();
});

$('.hoverLink').click(false);

});
```

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="hoverLink" href="#">
        <img class="littleFoo" src="#littleA" />
        <img class="bigFoo" src="#bigA" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Make sure you're using valid html elements. There is no image tag.
 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

EDIT:
This interaction can be done completely in CSS, no JavaScript necessary.

alternative JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($){ //best way to do document.ready

$('#hover-list li').mouseenter(function(e){
 $(this).find('img:eq(0)').hide();
 $(this).find('img:eq(1)').show();
});

$('#hover-list li').mouseleave(function(e){
  $(this).find('img:eq(0)').show();
  $(this).find('img:eq(1)').hide();
});

$('#hover-list li').click(false);

});
```

and the html is more simple:

```
  <ul id="hover-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#littleA" alt="DONT FORGET YOUR ALT TEXT" />
        <img src="#bigA" alt="DONT FORGET YOUR ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Really, classes and id's shouldn't be that much of an effort, unless you're hand coding.

And here's some CSS with **just one ID**

```
#hover-list li img
{
  display: inline;
}

#hover-list li img + img
{
  display: none;
}

#hover-list li:hover img
{
  display: none;
}

#hover-list li:hover img + img
{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: originally, i was going to use CSS only. problem is, how do you get around writing a separate class or id for each image? this is a gallery and will have maybe as many as 2000 images.

Comment: If you're working with a gallery of 2k images, and you're worried about a couple of classes or id's...
Maybe use a bit of server-scripting to automatically create the gallery from the images that are present in a directory for the gallery.

Comment: zzzzBov, i think your CSS will work. i usually prefer CSS because i'm more familiar with it, not to mention 508 compliance. but i like to learn new things. btw, i have the img tag in my code, but when i tried to make this post, i kept getting flagged that since i was a new user, i couldn't post images. so i was trying to work around that but still show what i was trying to do. this is a project for home that i'm doing. as it develops, i will pass a variable from the link to a main image page that will display the full size (the really large one) on a separate page. will post final markup/CSS.

Comment: copy-pasta your code into the editor, then select the code and hit the "Code Sample" button (Ctrl+K shortcut). It should auto-escape your tags and preserve your formatting.